# How to authenticate process configure in the project

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Work on ASP.NET Core with Angular project it's based on aspnetboilerplate framework, need to authenticate. Looking document **[Authorization](http://%20https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization)** but failed to configure the application for authenticating and authorized on role base.

Need guideline/example how to implement the authenticate process in aspnetboilerplate framework project.

Comment: do you want to authenticate from a 3rd party software?

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu want JWT authentication for all controllers each event and also want role-based authentication configuration.

Comment: Read the documentation: [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Permission-Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Permission-Management)